# How does the thrust achieved in my model differ from a rocket engine?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, rocket-science, propulsion

I am experimenting with a design that looks this,
using both straight and 90 degree curved pipes:

[image: 1]

I am supplying compressed air marked by yellow arrows and the pipe is producing a very small force in the direction opposite the arrow direction.

My question is how does this actually produce force, I am assuming it's not the same way a rocket engine by expelling mass, but instead by the pressure being created on the wall of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total thrust in all cases will just be the surface integral as follows:

F = $\int \rho u (u \cdot \bar n) dA   +\int (p - p_{ref}) \cdot \bar n  dA$

That is, the thrust in an internal flow is the sum of the force due to mass flux and the pressure fluxes, where $u$ is the velocity field, $\rho$ the density, $\bar n $ the normal vector over the closed surface $dS$, $p$ is the pressure and $p_{ref}$ some reference pressure (e.g. ambient pressure). This is true for any system (nozzle, diffusers, intake flows etc.) as it simply comes from conservation of momentum, regardless of the type of geometry in question.

Usually we take the surface integral along the exit plane of the nozzle (which corresponds to the force in the opposite direction, as a Newton pair), i.e. $\bar n = \hat x$, $dA = dA_e$, so whether or not the thrust emitting from different geometries are larger or not depends on the mass flow rate and the force due to pressure difference. From this, we can infer that the pressure fluxes on the wall should not really contribute to the thrust, since that does not make sense physically in terms of the surface integral quantities.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would a rocket engine work in a "similar" manner? What I mean by that is the mass flux would be what creates the thrust and pressure flux would be negligible? From what I'm guessing with my pressurized air experiment the thrust is mostly produced by pressure fluxes (on the walls - that's why there's actually very little thrust produced) as opposed to mass fluxes? I just wanted to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Yes the rocket engine does work in a similar manner. The mass flux dominates but the pressure flux is not necessarily negligible, since the nozzle exit pressure can be quite different from the ambient (back) pressure (see overexpanded/underexpanded flows). Regardless, the thrust just comes from Newton force pairs, so if forces are exerted onto the wall, it will produce a reaction force in the wall-normal direction, and not opposite the streamwise direction (they are surface integrals). This means that the force you get on the walls, do not contribute to the thrust (red arrow in your diagram).

Comment: You should be able to evaluate this just by performing numerical integration with discrete data along the exit plane, and quantify the pressure flux there to see whether that gives the majority of the thrust.